# I want for the login class to access the database connection from different class

Tags: java

I want to separate the db connection from the other classes so I don't need to write again the db connection for every class I want to create.

This is the db connection class

```
package bloodbank;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class dbconnection {
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

public dbconnection() {}

public void connect() {
try {
     Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    Connection con = 
 DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;
 databaseName=BloodManagementSystem;user=yusuf;password=ali1234");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
  }

 }

public PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String select__from_Users_where_Username_and_Pas) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
}
```

And this is the login class with login button

```
import bloodbank.dbconnection;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class login extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public login() {
    initComponents();
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed

    try
    {

       dbconnection con = new dbconnection();
       con.connect();

    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("Select * from Users where Username=? and Password=?");
   pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText()); 
   pst.setString(2, jTextField2.getText());
   ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery(); 
   if(rs.next()) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and Password correct");
       Mainform field = new Mainform();
       field.setVisible(true);
       setVisible(false);


        } else {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "invalid username and password");
        } 
    }
    catch(SQLException | HeadlessException e){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

   }   


   }

public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        new login().setVisible(true);
    });
}

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea. What's the question?

Comment: i would like for someone to test this code because when i run it, it shows many errors like this

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: bloodbank.dbconnection.prepareStatement
 at login.jButton1ActionPerformed(login.java:95)
 at login.access$000(login.java:9)
 at login$1.actionPerformed(login.java:51)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to use only one connection across your application. You should use a singleton-style class for `dbconnection`. Have a `private static Connection cnx` variable to store the connection and check if a connection is established before attempting to create a new one every time.

```
public class dbconnection {
    private static Connection cnx = null;

    public Connection getConnection() {
        if(cnx == null) {
            cnx = (... initialize the connection ...)
        return cnx
    }
}
```

Call `Connection con = dbconnection.getConnection()` to get a reference to the database connection in-place of the current `.connect()`.

You also shouldn't store the database credentials in the source code. Hard-coding a secret account and password into your software is extremely convenient -- for skilled reverse engineers. If the password is the same across all your software, then every customer becomes vulnerable when that password inevitably becomes known. And because it's hard-coded, it's a huge pain to fix.

For a quick and dirty solution/small hack it's fine, but for production purposes you should store configuration information, including passwords, in a separate file that the application reads when it starts. That is the only real way to prevent the password from leaking as a result of decompilation (never compile it into the binary to begin with)

Comment: i am new programmer but i appreciate ur tips thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your Connection static and initialize it on first call to getConnection method. Like this code:

```
package com.stackoverflow.json;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class dbconnection {

    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    private static Connection con;

    public dbconnection() {
    }

    private static void connect() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433; databaseName=BloodManagementSystem;user=yusuf;password=ali1234");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        }

    }

    public PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String select__from_Users_where_Username_and_Pas) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        if (con == null)
            connect();
        return con;
    }
}
```

You can additionally create class called DBUtils which contains all methods to query database with jdbc.